# File not saving as .png

Tags: javascript, electron

I have been making this app in electron.js which takes photos and saves them. I am currently trying to develop the file saving part, but I have encountered an error. When I try to save the file, no errors come up, but the file does not save as a .png. Instead, the file just saves as a regular file.

File Explorer:

[image: Image of the save location]

Image.js:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

var date = Date()

date = date.replace(':', '')
date = date.replace(/ /g, '')
date = date += '.png'

const logError = err => err && console.error(err)

exports.save = (picturesPath, contents) => {
    const base64Data = contents.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, '')
    fs.writeFile(path.join(picturesPath, `${date}.png`), base64Data, { encoding: 'base64' }, logError)
}

exports.getPicturesDir = app => {
    return path.join(app.getPath('pictures'), 'photobombth')
}
exports.mkdir = picturesPath => {
    fs.stat(picturesPath, (err, stats) => {
        if (err && err.code !== 'ENOENT')
            return logError(err)
        else if (err || !stats.isDirectory())
            fs.mkdir(picturesPath, logError)
    })
}
```

Please tell me if you need anymore code. I am a beginner to electron and javascript - :)
Thanks!

Comment: try this https://gist.github.com/Venugopal46/0728be2721ec0193b16ca50c617f409b

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you mean. Do you mean replace the entire code with this? Or something else?